# oauth2 integration test with spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockmvc

I'm having issues writing integration tests for my application. Manually testing the integration works perfectly fine as expected; just having issues writing the integration test. I followed the guide from https://www.baeldung.com/oauth-api-testing-with-spring-mvc, but it doesn't seem to work on my application. (not sure if it's because I'm using JUnit5). I really don't know what exactly I'm missing. The request keeps responding at the end with a 401 forbidden instead of a 200 on a post request to setup a new access token.

application.yml

```
spring:
  profiles: test
security:
  oauth:
    client:
      client-id: client-id
      client-secret: client-secret
```

IntegrationTest

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class MyIntegrationTest {

    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Autowired
    private FilterChainProxy filterChainProxy;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @Value("${security.oauth2.client.client-id}")
    private String clientId;

    @Value("${security.oauth2.client.client-secret}")
    private String clientSecret;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
                .addFilter(filterChainProxy).build();
    }

    private String obtainAccessToken() throws Exception {
        MultiValueMap<String, String> params = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        params.add("grant_type", "client_credentials");
        params.add("client_id", clientId);
        params.add("client_secret", clientSecret);
        params.add("scope", "any");

        String mvcResult = mvc.perform(post("/oauth/token")
            .params(params)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andReturn()
            .getResponse().getContentAsString();

        return new JacksonJsonParser().parseMap(mvcResult).get("access_token").toString();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

What's actually missing is the authorization of the client. Needed to add the authorization headers.

```
private String obtainAccessToken() throws Exception {
        MultiValueMap<String, String> params = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        params.add("grant_type", "client_credentials");
        params.add("scope", "any");

        String mvcResult = mvc.perform(post("/oauth/token")
            .params(params)
             // including authorization headers
            .headers("Authorization", "Basic " + new String(Base64Utils.encode((clientId + ":" + clientSecret).getBytes()))))
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE))
            .andReturn()
            .getResponse().getContentAsString();

        return new JacksonJsonParser().parseMap(mvcResult).get("access_token").toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this:

```
MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON
```

on this:

```
MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE
```

or this, as in the example:

```
"application/json;charset=UTF-8"
```